# How to change mongodb data directory ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, permissions

I want to change my mongodb data directory to my external media. I have done a lot of search and tried many ways, but could not achieve it.
The problem is that when I change data dir to my media (other than home dir), it does not work, but it works for home dir:

I follow these steps:

```
sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Then, changed:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /home/nimashiri/mongodb
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:
```

Then:

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /home/nimashiri/mongodb
```

When I try for my disk dir, it gives the following error:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-11-22 12:46:57 EST; 3s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 144014 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
   Main PID: 144014 (code=exited, status=100)

Nov 22 12:46:57 nimashiri-G5-5000 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Nov 22 12:46:57 nimashiri-G5-5000 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
Nov 22 12:46:57 nimashiri-G5-5000 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you change the /data path in the config file?

Comment: @Shekhar yes I get ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-11-22 12:26:20 EST; 5s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 142361 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
   Main PID: 142361 (code=exited, status=100)

Nov 22 12:26:20 nimashiri-G5-5000 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
code=exited, status=100/n/a

Comment: can you povide the mongod.service file?

Comment: How can I find it?

Comment: @Shekhar, when I change dir to home dir, it works. I just change data dir in mongodb.conf and run ```sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /home/nimashiri/mongodb/```

Comment: /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service this is the service file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249813/discussion-between-shekhar-and-nima-shiri).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used compiled binaries to achieve my goal. You may follow [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-tarball/).